# Get popularity of has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following models & relationships

```
Category
  has_many :candy
  # these are examples
  #"Hard Candy" "Gummies" "Rock Candy" "Gum" "Jawbreakers" "Lollipops" "Licorice" "Liquid Candy" "Powder Candy" "Taffy"

CandyCategory
  belongs_to :candy
  belongs_to :category

Candy
  has_many :candy_categories
  # Examples "Lemon Drop", "Tootsie Rolls", "Blow Pop", "Ring Pop", "Fun Dip"

Likes
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :candy
  has_many :categories, through: :candy
  # there is some meta data here, but the important bits are just the relationships
```

I'm trying to derive the most popular category names  based on the likes of the candy itself.

I can group by the category name, and get a count, but that (obviously) won't leave me with the category object, just an array with the name and count.

e.g.

```
Like.includes(:categories).references(:categories).group("categories.name").count
```

Can someone knock some sense into me today and show me the error of my ActiveRecordee ways!?! At the end of the day I need a list of Category objects, or at least the category name and id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EUREKA!!!!

So, apparently I was psyching myself out over this, it wasn't difficult, I was just thinking of it in reverse.

Here's the solution:

```
Category.joins(:candy).includes(:likes).group(:categories).count
```